# A possible issue with Service Worker which prevents website from working offline

Tags: service-worker

I created a new website and added a service worker. It gets installed but refuses to work offline. I am loading all resources from cache explicitly by specifying all the URL's.  Could someone explain why is the main request failing?

[image: Requests snapshot]

Link: http://ashutoshysingh.com/sw.js

**Update 1:**
I have readded the index.html file in cache.

1. Error shown in Firefox console:

Failed to load 'https://www.ashutoshysingh.com/'. A ServiceWorker passed a promise to FetchEvent.respondWith() that rejected with 'TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.'.

2. Error in Chrome console:

The FetchEvent for "https://www.ashutoshysingh.com/" resulted in a network error response: the promise was rejected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your appshell (index.html or similar) to the cache as well:

```
caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
  return cache.addAll([
        '/', or 'index.html',
        'assets/css/styles.css',
        ...,
```

Comment: Sorry, I had removed index.html for testing. Even after adding it, the website doesn't operate without the network. I have updated the question with the exact error.

Comment: This is not the issue and it will not solve anything